# No Web API refetch on parameter value change on powerbi report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to make a REST API call from Power BI whenever there is a change in parameter values.

##### Expected Result:

Every time when the report user changes the values of parameters from Power BI filter pane or slicer my report should make an API call and re-fetch the new data.

##### Below are the current specification/configuration that I am using:

1. Oracle report service REST API which brings the data from on prem Oracle Database. This API consist of parameters like: FromDate, ToDate. For example, http://host_server/report?params=&Date.ToText(FromDate_param)&"|"&Dare.ToText(ToDate_param)&.
   Date Parameter format is “yyyymmdd”.
2. I am using Power BI Web Connector to connect to this JSON API.
3. I have created Date Dimension tables with FromDate and ToDate date columns.
4. I bind these columns to parameters - FromDate_param, ToDate_param.
5. I am using FromDate and ToDate in Filter pane of the report.

##### Issue:

When user selects new dates from filter pane of the report and click on Apply, the data in the report do not get re-loaded on the basis of new values selected by the user. Instead, it loads the data based on the default values of the parameter which was set at the time of creation of these parameters.
1.
So basically, the data doesn’t change when the parameter values are changed by user from power bi report.

Please also comment on if an **odata(Open Data Protocol) API** can help me achieve this.

Thank you!